# Регистрация на сайте с помощью ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Делаю регистрацию на сайте в учебных целях. Хочу запретить создавать пользователей с одинаковым логином. Проверку на одинаковый логин делаю в реализации интерфейса. Вот код:

```
public void Add_New_User(User user)
{
    User olduser = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.LoginUser == user.LoginUser);
    if (olduser == null)
    {
        context.Users.Add(user);
    }
    else
    {
         throw new Exception();
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

То есть если пользователя с таким логином нет, то я регистрирую его. Если же пользователь с таким логином есть, то выпихиваю ошибку(И вот эту ошибку я хочу изменить на что то более красивое. Например: на сообщение "Пользователь с таким логином уже есть").

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: @PavelMayorov? Ну смотрите. Если пользователь регистрируется, а в БД уже есть пользователь с таким логином, то его регистрацию нужно запретить...

Comment: Ну так запрещайте. Вопрос-то в чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посидел. Подумал. И решил, что лучше перенести логику проверки в контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registr(User user, HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                user.IconUserType = image.ContentType;
                user.IconUserData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(user.IconUserData, 0, image.ContentLength);
            }

            User olduser = repository.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.LoginUser == user.LoginUser);

            if (olduser != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Такой пользователь уже есть");
            }

            if (user.Password == Request.Form["Повторите пароль"] && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Регистрация прошла успешно! Можете логиниться";
                repository.Add_New_User(user);
                return Redirect("/Account/Login"); //С помошью такого перевода мы избегам ошибки, когда при перегрузке браузера мы два раза отправляем одни и теже данные
            }
            else if(user.Password != Request.Form["Повторите пароль"])
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пароли не совпадают");
            }

           return View("Registr");
        }
```

Можно ли как то это все упростить, а то мне кажется, что данный контроллер получился уж слишком большим...

Answer (score -1):

Почему делаете в методе, а не в ActionResult ? 
Можно использовать remote Validation - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d87001/remote-validation-in-mvc/

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Class RegisterViewModel

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Не указан логин")>
    <Display(Name:="Логин")>
    <RegularExpression("[A-z0-9_]{5,15}", ErrorMessage:="Допустимые символы - латиница, нижнее подчеркивание, цифры (5-15 символов)")>
    Public Property Login As String ' имя пользователя (логин) проверка на уникальность
End Class
```

проверка

```
If olduser IsNot Nothing Then
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует")
End If
```